# Python and mail regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a small regexp checker for mail with following conditions:

1) domain name between 2 and 128 symbols (numbers, alphabet and *.-) = **/^[a-z0-9***_.-]{2,128}$/

2) minus symbol - not in the begining or the end of the login or domain name = **/^[^-]*|[^-]*$/**

3) account name not less then 64 symbols = **/^.{64,}$/**

4) two dots together are disallowed = **/^([^.]|([^.]).[^.])*$/**

5) if double quotes would exist in the string they will be twin (have a pair)

6) !,: - could exist between double quotes

What could I use from the regexp to perform theese conditions and bring them together in accordance with claims?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Do not write your own regular expression for email addresses. Thousands of people have re-invented this wheel. Here is one example, from http://code.iamcal.com/php/rfc822/full_regexp.txt

```
(((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*
))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+
)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00
-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x0
9]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\
x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x2
0\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\
x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7
f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\
x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?(
?:(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e])+
(?:\x2e(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x
7e])+)*)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]
+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x0
9]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\
x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20
\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x
20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[
\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x2
1-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-
\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*)
)?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*)))
)?))|((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09
]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x
09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[
\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x2
0\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\
x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?
[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x
21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00
-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*
))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))
))?\x22(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*)
)?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0
b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))+(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:
[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x22(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(
?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)
|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-
\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(
?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?
:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28
(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?
:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\
x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\
x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x2
0\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?))|((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x
09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20
\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x
27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f
]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x
29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?
(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*)
)?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x
09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+
)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|
(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?(?:(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27
\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e]))+(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+
)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09
]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x
2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f])))
)*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))
*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\
x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?
:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x
0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?
:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[
\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?)|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)
|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]
+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2
A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))
*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*
(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x
28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:
(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0
b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:
[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\
x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?\x22(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[
\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\
x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))+(?:(?:(?:[\
x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x22(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:
[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(
?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x0
8\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x
7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(
?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]
+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x0
9]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7
e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x2
0\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\
x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?))(?:\x2e(?:(?:(?:(?:
(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(
?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:
[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x
0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x
20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[
\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?
:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5
b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(
?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:
(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?(?:(?:[\x41-
\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e]))+(?:(?:(?:(
?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?
:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x0
1-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x
0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x
09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20
\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x
20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5
d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?
:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[
\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?)|(?:(?:(?:(?:(?
:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:
(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01
-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0
e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x0
9]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\
x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x2
0\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d
-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:
[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\
x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?\x22(?:(?:(?:(?:[
\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x
0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*
\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))+(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0
d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x22(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\
x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?
:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\
x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(
?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]
*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x0
9]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\
x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x
0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\
x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0
a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?)))*)))\x40(((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x0
9]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\
x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\
x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\
x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:
[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(
?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x0
8\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x
7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(
?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:
(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?(?:(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\
x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e])+(?:\x2e(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d
\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e])+)*)(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20
\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x
20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5
d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?
:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:
(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(
?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-
\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e
-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09
]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+
(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?))|((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x2
0\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\
x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x
5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(
?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?
:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:
(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01
-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0
e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x0
9]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]
+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?\x5b(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09
]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x5a\x5e-\x7e])|(?:\x5
c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:
\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x5d(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(
?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]
*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0
e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d
*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0
a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\
x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0
d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(
?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x
0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d
\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?))|((?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x0
9]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\
x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0
c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*
\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0
d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\
x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?
:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\
x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(
?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:
\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?(?:(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[\
x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e]))+(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(
?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]
*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0
e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d
*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0
a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\
x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0
d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(
?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x
0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d
\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?)(?:\x2e(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x
09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20
\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x
0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a
*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x
0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:
\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(
?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:
\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*
(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?
:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?(?:(?:[\x41-\x5a\x61-\x7a]|[
\x30-\x39]|[\x21\x23-\x27\x2a\x2b\x2d\x2f\x3d\x3f\x5e\x5f\x60\x7b-\x7e]))+(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*
(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09
]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x
0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0
d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x
0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29))*(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d
\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:\x28(?:(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x
0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?(?:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|[\x21-\x27\x2A-\x5b\x5d-\x7e])|(?:\x5c
(?:\x0a*\x0d*[\x00-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f]\x0a*\x0d*)|(?:\x5c[\x00-\x7f]))))*(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\
x0d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))?\x29)|(?:(?:(?:[\x20\x09]*(?:\x0
d\x0a))?[\x20\x09]+)|(?:[\x20\x09]+(?:(?:\x0d\x0a)[\x20\x09]+)*))))?))*)))
```

Comment: it's so long !!

Comment: Too much for an email regex, try this: [emailregex](https://emailregex.com/), they state that works 99.99% of the times.

Answer (score 0):

use this `/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/i` and make some changes accordingly if you want but this is a standard one that goes with most of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `self regex` using below tool:

```
http://www.txt2re.com/
```

This tool is very cool

Hope this help you.